# Get Daylight Saving Transition Dates For Time Zones in C

Tags: c, timezone, dst

In C, is there a simple, cross-platform way of retrieving the dates that a given timezone begins and ends daylight saving?

I already have timezone offset information and whether or not daylight savings is currently being observed, but I really need the dates at which daylight savings begins and ends (for  an external dependency I don't control).  In Windows, I'm using [GetTimeZoneInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724421(VS.85).aspx) to get [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx), but I can't find a similar function for Linux/Solaris/Mac.
I should point out also that I can't just rely on US rules for daylight savings adoption, as I can't predict the countries it will be used in.

The only way I'm aware of to get this information is via [zdump](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/zdump8.html) or perhaps looking directly at the /usr/share/lib/zoneinfo files themselves, but I was hoping for a better solution.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you find answer to your question?
I need function similar to GetTimeZoneInformation() for Linux.

Comment: I have precisely the same question about Java

Comment: No, I didn't find any usable solution as I need the solution to work in Solaris as well as Mac and Linux, however I think tgamblin's answer is probably the closest you would get to a workable solution.
I haven't tried to do this in Java, so I can't help I'm afraid; I know that Java is supposed to use the Olson DB, but it doesn't seem to expose the DST date change info.

Answer (score 5):

The portable and **consistent** way to deal with this is to **build a year-round TZ offset table** (for each day in the current year in the current timezone) at application startup.  Resolve each day's midnight local time to UTC (GMT), and record the effective timezone offset vis-a-vis UTC (GMT) for the day in question.  Look for transitions in the effective TZ offsets year-round (transitions will indicate DST changes.)  This approach is **consistent and portable** in that only depends on `localtime`/`gmtime` functioning reliably on the platform in question, and will return results fully consistent with `localtime`/`gmtime` calls.  However, it becomes a bit **more complicated if you require DST information for other timezones** (than the process' default timezone.)

You can also **directly use the [TZ/Olson database](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm)** (code available for both *nix and Windows), for **maximum flexibility**, but unless the underlying runtime/OS use the exact same timezone information (and your application uses TZ/Olson timezone information *and* `gmtime`/`localtime` interchangeably) then you're in for unpleasant surprises.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's a good cross-platform way to do this, but there is a programmatic interface to the `/usr/share/zoneinfo` files (or at least a description of the format) in [`tzfile.h`](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=5&topic=tzfile), (available on Mac OS X and Linux).

Windows uses slightly different mappings from tzinfo, but there's a [conversion table](http://unicode.org/cldr/data/diff/supplemental/windows_tzid.html) you could use to generify your interface between Windows and Unix.

Comment: tzfile.h does not describe much at all... It has a header, that's kind of it... I wonder why people write stuff like that. The time functions in libc must be able to read that data, why not make that public?!

Answer (score 1):

> In C, is there a simple, cross-platform way of retrieving the dates that a given timezone > begins and ends daylight saving?

No.

I implemented TZ support on VMS for DEC back in the late 90s.

Firstly, there is no cross-platform solution.

Secondly, the dates vary from year to year and also by legislative fiat.  There is in fact no fully reliable *programmatic* solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need C++ (not C) look to boost::date_time library http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/date_time.html