# How do I convert boost::posix_time::ptime to time_t?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

Is there some "standard" way or the best I can do is to compute it directly by subtracting from `gregorian::date(1970,1,1)`?

Comment: Just a thought; I'm using boost::posix_time::from_time_t(0) instead of explicit time in Gregorian calendar, to get a reference-point that will automatically adjust to the epoch of the system compiled for.

Comment: @Rawler, that's likely much better -- I've found that the actual epoch is apparently 2000ns prior to what's represented by `gregorian::date(1970,1,1)`.

Comment: @BrianCain Where did you come up with 2000ns before the infamous epoch timestamp? As far as I remember and have read, I've always heard that epoch is 1970-01-01 00:00:00.0 UTC.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`time_t` is the type used to hold time in seconds (typically epoch time). I'm guessing you are after epoch time, if so I'm not aware of any way in boost of actually getting epoch time directly, aside from the subtraction you have already. Once you have a `time_duration` (result of the subtraction), you can call `total_seconds()` on the duration and store that in `time_t`.

btw. if you are after epoch time, you could simple use `gettimeofday()` and save yourself some headache!

Answer (score 39):

Since @icecrime's method converts twice (ptime uses linear representation internally), I've decided to use direct computation instead. Here it is:

```
time_t to_time_t(boost::posix_time::ptime t)
{
    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    ptime epoch(boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1));
    time_duration::sec_type x = (t - epoch).total_seconds();

    // ... check overflow here ...

    return time_t(x);
}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks @jaaw for bringing this to my attention. Since boost 1.58 this function is included in `date_time/posix_time/conversion.hpp`, `std::time_t to_time_t(ptime pt)`.

Comment: such a pity that they've not added this as a direct function call in the library... I wonder what the reasons were...

Comment: could make ptime epoch static versus computing every call.

Comment: use std::time_t posix_time::to_time_t(posix_time::ptime pt) in conversion.hpp

Comment: @jaaw: Thanks, it was added just recently.

Comment: Note that, as [@kgriffs says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849810/25507), `total_seconds()` uses 32 bits (at least on my 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 system), so it overflows after 2038. Boost's own `to_time_t` uses this same implementation, so it also has this same limitation.

Comment: Keep in mind that a `ptime` can also have several special values (`not_a_date_time`, `pos_infin`, and `neg_infin`). Adding `assert(!t.is_special());` may be a good idea. (Boost's own `to_time_t` doesn't check for `is_special` either.)

Answer (score 15):

Here's a variation of @ybungalobill's method that will get you past 2038, just in case. :)

```
int64_t rax::ToPosix64(const boost::posix_time::ptime& pt)
{
  using namespace boost::posix_time;
  static ptime epoch(boost::gregorian::date(1970, 1, 1));
  time_duration diff(pt - epoch);
  return (diff.ticks() / diff.ticks_per_second());
}
```

Comment: Yes, but when you are writing a cross-platform app, you have to support 32-bit as well.

Comment: @ybungalobill: The problem isn't so much `time_t` but `time_duration::sec_type` which is 32-bit (at least on my machine).

Comment: Keep in mind that a `ptime` can also have several special values (`not_a_date_time`, `pos_infin`, and `neg_infin`). Adding `assert(!pt.is_special());` may be a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the best you can do is using [`to_tm`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#ptime_struct_tm) to get a `tm` and [`mktime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/mktime/) to convert the `tm` to a `time_t`.

Comment: But I believe mktime has implicit time zone adjustment (it shows number of seconds from epoch in local time)'

Answer (score 2):

These 2 lines should do it.

```
tm td_tm = to_tm(pt);
time_t tt = mktime(&td_tm);
```

Comment: The thing to be careful with this and icecrime's solution above is posix mktime's input contract. mktime takes a struct "expressed as local time, to calendar time representation" and converts it for you. However, boost p_time does not do any TZ conversion for you when filling out the tm struct. So if you're looking for an absolute epoch time as # of seconds since UTC Jan 1, 1970 midnight and your machine's local TZ is not GMT, this call isn't going to get you what you want. Subtracting an explicitly constructed epoch and taking the second difference is clear, obvious and tz-safe.