# Convert between boost::posix_time::ptime and mongo::Date_t

Tags: c++, datetime, mongodb, boost

Is there a succinct way, or a generally accepted way to convert from a `boost::posix_time::ptime` to a `mongo::Date_t` and back again?

#### Mongo to Boost

The [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#ptime_from_funcs) seems incomplete or incorrect. It documents a function `date_from_tm` which constructs a `date` struct from a `tm`. However, the following example is given:

```
tm pt_tm;
/* snip */
ptime pt = ptime_from_tm(pt_tm);
```

But there is no documented function `ptime_from_tm`. However [this header file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/date_time/posix_time/conversion.hpp) *does include* that function.

So, I can at least go from `mongo::Date_t` to `boost::posix_time::ptime`:

```
mongo::Date_t d = ...;
std::tm t;
d.toTm(&t);
boost::posix_time::ptime pt = ptime_from_tm(t);
```

#### Boost to Mongo

I'm kind of stuck when it comes to going in the opposite direction. The [MongoDB documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/2.1.0/structmongo_1_1_date__t.html) is rather incomplete, and the associated [header file](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/2.1.0/misc_8h_source.html) doesn't have many helpful comments. Basically, the `Date_t` struct is constructed from an `unsigned long long` millisecond count. I can only *assume* from the 1970-1-1:00:00.00 epoch.

So my current solution to go from a `boost::posix_time::ptime` to a `mongo::Date_t` is:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime pt = ...;
std::tm pt_tm = boost::posix_time::to_tm(pt);
std::time_t t = mktime(pt_tm);
mongo::Date_t d(t);
```

Of course, I can probably collapse that into one line, but it seems that the whole round trip from one date/time representation to the other and  back again is becoming convoluted and messy.

### Finally

Is there a better way? Does anybody with a better knowledge of both libraries and a good understanding of date/time programming know a succinct, simple way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: mktime(pt_tm) should be mktime(&pt_tm)? And do a conversion from ptime to Date_t, the result is incorrect. the ptime is "2011-10-28 23:30:30.000" but I get "Fri Jan 16 13:36:55 1970" in Date_t. mongo driver 2.4.3, boost 1530

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically, the Date_t struct is constructed from an unsigned long long millisecond count. I can only *assume* from the 1970-1-1:00:00.00 epoch.

You are correct.

I think your code is about as good as you're going to get.  You have to somehow get to a time_t-like seconds-since-the epoch, which seems to be [a little complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461586/how-do-i-convert-boostposix-timeptime-to-time-t) with ptime.

Answer (score 3):

It seems your solution convert from ptime to Date_t has some problem, I try it and get incorrect result as I commented.
I have a better way:

```
mongo::Date_t convert(const boost::posix_time::ptime& time)
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime epoch(boost::gregorian::date(1970,boost::date_time::Jan,1));
    boost::posix_time::time_duration d = time - epoch;
    return mongo::Date_t(d.total_milliseconds());
}
boost::posix_time::ptime convert(const mongo::Date_t& time)
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime epoch(boost::gregorian::date(1970,boost::date_time::Jan,1));
    boost::posix_time::time_duration d = boost::posix_time::milliseconds(time.millis);//- epoch;
    return boost::posix_time::ptime(epoch+d);
}
```

Notice that 2.4.3(as I know) Date_t::toString() has bug, the 'date' has been add 8 hours. You can verify 'total milliseconds' at [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/)