# Why we substract the unix epoch from boost::posix_time::ptime to obtain time_t

Tags: c++, boost, unix-timestamp

could someone please explain why we need to subtract boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1) from a boost::posix_time::ptime to obtain a POSIX notation of time (i.e. microseconds since 1970,1,1 midnight UTC time zone)

For example this link provides clear instructions, but not the reason:

[How do I convert boost::posix_time::ptime to time_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461586/how-do-i-convert-boostposix-timeptime-to-time-t)

Thanks

Comment: That link describes how to convert a _specific point in time_ to a _duration of time_.  Are you familiar with the difference?

Comment: I think it's interesting that the `ptime` class includes a conversion from `time_t` that explicitly documents the involvement of the UNIX epoch: `ptime from_time_t(std::time_t)` - "Creates a ptime from the time_t parameter. The seconds held in the time_t are added to a time point of 1970-Jan-01", but there is no inverse function. I wonder why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are converting a *date* to a *time*.

From the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) :

**Posix Time**

> Defines a non-adjusted time system with nano-second/micro-second
>   resolution and stable calculation properties [...] **This time system uses the Gregorian calendar to implement the date portion of the time representation**.

So `boost::posix_time::p_time` is not just the epoch time (as return by `time()`, for example)), but rather the **date and the time**, expressed (obviously) since the beginning of the Gregorian calendar.

So if you want a Posix Epoch **Time** (from since 1970,1,1 midnight UTC time zone), you will need to do the subtraction of all those years.