# How to get seconds from boost::posix_time::ptime

Tags: c++, boost, time, posix, epoch

First off: I'm a very new to Boost and somewhat new to C++, too. 
I',m working with a  function where I get the following `boost::posix_time::ptime time` passed as an argument and I want to extract the `POSIX` time aka "seconds since epoch" from this as `long`. How do I do this?

Comment: Use `to_time_t` function [see more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461586/how-do-i-convert-boostposix-timeptime-to-time-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `ptime` to [`std::tm`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm), and convert that to `time_t` using [`mktime()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime):

```
#include <ctime>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

boost::posix_time::ptime time;
std::tm time_tm = to_tm(time);
time_t posix_time = mktime(&time_tm);
```

As [rafix07](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8950365/rafix07) pointed out, there is also `to_time_t()` in `boost/date_time/posix_time/conversion.hpp`, which does this conversion directly. I did not find documentation about it, but I checked the source code and it exists at least in Boost 1.66.