# C++ vs. python: daylight saving time not recognized when extracting Unix time?

Tags: python, c++, date, time

I'm attempting to calculate the Unix time of a given date and time represented by two integers, e.g.

`testdate1 = 20060711` (July 11th, 2006)

`testdate2 = 4` (00:00:04, 4 seconds after midnight)

in a timezone other than my local timezone. To calculate the Unix time, I feed `testdate1`, `testdate2` into a function I adapted from [Convert date to unix time stamp in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679056/convert-date-to-unix-time-stamp-in-c)

```
int unixtime (int testdate1, int testdate2) {

time_t rawtime; 
struct tm * timeinfo; 

//time1, ..., time6 are external functions that extract the 
//year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds digits from testdate1, testdate2

int year=time1(testdate1);
int month=time2(testdate1);
int day=time3(testdate1);
int hour=time4(testdate2);
int minute=time5(testdate2);
int second=time6(testdate2);

time ( &rawtime );
timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );  

timeinfo->tm_year   = year - 1900; 
timeinfo->tm_mon    = month - 1;   
timeinfo->tm_mday   = day;         
timeinfo->tm_hour   = hour;        
timeinfo->tm_min    = minute;          
timeinfo->tm_sec    = second;       

int date;
date = mktime(timeinfo);

return date;

}
```

Which I call from the main code

```
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

int testdate1 = 20060711;
int testdate2 = 4;


//switch to CET time zone 
setenv("TZ","Europe/Berlin", 1); 
tzset();

cout << testdate1 << "\t" << testdate2 << "\t" << unixtime(testdate1,testdate2) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

With the given example, I get `unixtime(testdate1,testdate2) = 1152572404`, which according to

https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1152572404&tz=Europe%2FBerlin

is 1:00:04 am CEST, but I want this to be 0:00:04 CEST.

The code seems to work perfectly well if I choose a `testdate1`, `testdate2` in which daylight saving time (DST) *isn't* being observed. For example, simply setting the month to February with all else unchanged is accomplished by setting `testdate1 = 20060211`. This gives
`unixtime(testdate1,testdate2) = 1139612404`, corresponding to hh:mm:ss = 00:00:04 in CET, as desired.

My impression is that `setenv("TZ","Europe/Berlin", 1)` is supposed to account for DST when applicable, but perhaps I am mistaken. Can TZ interpret `testdate1`, `testdate2` in such a way that it accounts for DST?

Interestingly, I have a python code that performs the same task by changing the local time via `os.environ['TZ'] = 'Europe/Berlin'`. Here I have no issues, as it seems to calculate the correct Unix time regardless of DST/non-DST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localtime` sets `timeinfo->tm_isdst` to that of the *current* time - not of the date you parse.

Don't call `localtime`. Set `timeinfo->tm_isdst` to `-1`:

> The value specified in the `tm_isdst` field informs `mktime()` whether or not daylight saving time (DST) is in effect for the time supplied in the tm structure: a positive value means DST is in effect; zero means that DST is not in effect; **and a negative value means that `mktime()` should (use timezone information and system databases to) attempt to determine whether DST is in effect at the specified time**.

See the code example in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime

Comment: Perfect reply and solution! My code now works exactly as I had hoped.

Comment: @renorm877 Thank you. You may also like to use `std::time_t` instead of `int`, as @howard-hinnant advises.

Answer (score 1):

Maxim's answer is correct, and I've upvoted it.  But I also thought it might be helpful to show how this can be done in C++20 using the newer `<chrono>` tools.  This isn't implemented everywhere yet, but it is here in Visual Studio and will be coming elsewhere soon.

There's two main points I'd like to illustrate here:

1. `<chrono>` is convenient for conversions like this, even if both the input and the output does not involve `std::chrono` types.  One can convert the integral input to chrono, do the conversion, and then convert the chrono result back to integral.
2. There's a thread safety weakness in using the `TZ` environment variable, as this is a type of global.  If another thread is also doing some type of time computation, it may not get the correct answer if the computer's time zone unexpectedly changes out from under it.  The `<chrono>` solution is thread-safe.  It doesn't involve globals or environment variables.

The first job is to unpack the integral data.  Here I show how to do this, and convert it into `chrono` types in one step:

```
std::chrono::year_month_day
get_ymd(int ymd)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    day d(ymd % 100);
    ymd /= 100;
    month m(ymd % 100);
    ymd /= 100;
    year y{ymd};
    return y/m/d;
}
```

`get_ymd` takes "`testdate1`", extracts the individual integral fields for day, month, and year, then converts each integral field into the `std::chrono` types `day`, `month` and `year`, and finally combines these three separate fields into a `std::chrono::year_month_day` to return it as one value.  This return type is simple a `{year, month, day}` data structure -- like a `tuple` but with calendrical meaning.

The `/` syntax is simply a convenient factory function for constructing a `year_month_day`.  And this construction can be done with any of these three orderings:  `y/m/d`, `d/m/y` and `m/d/y`.  This syntax, when combined with `auto`, also means that you often don't have to spell out the verbose name `year_month_day`:

```
auto
get_ymd(int ymd)
{
    // ...
    return y/m/d;
}
```

`get_hms` unpacks the hour, minute and second fields and returns that as a `std::chrono::seconds`:

```
std::chrono::seconds
get_hms(int hms)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    seconds s{hms % 100};
    hms /= 100;
    minutes m{hms % 100};
    hms /= 100;
    hours h{hms};
    return h + m + s;
}
```

The code is very similar to that for `get_ymd` except that the return is the sum of the hours, minutes and seconds.  The `chrono` library does the job for you of converting hours and minutes to seconds while performing the summation.

Next is the function for doing the conversion, and returning the result back as an `int`.

```
int
unixtime(int testdate1, int testdate2)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto ymd = get_ymd(testdate1);
    auto hms = get_hms(testdate2);
    auto ut = locate_zone("Europe/Berlin")->to_sys(local_days{ymd} + hms);
    return ut.time_since_epoch().count();
}
```

`std::chrono::locate_zone` is called to get a pointer to the `std::chrono::time_zone` with the name "Europe/Berlin".  The std::lib manages the lifetime of this object, so you don't have to worry about it.  It is a `const` singleton, created on demand.  And it has no impact on what time zone your computer considers its "local time zone".

The `std::chrono::time_zone` has a member function called `to_sys` that takes a `local_time`, and converts it to a `sys_time`, using the proper UTC offset for this time zone (taking into account daylight saving rules when applicable).

Both `local_time` and `sys_time` are `std::chrono::time_point` types.  `local_time` is "some local time", not necessarily your computer's local time.  You can associate a local time with a time zone in order to specify the locality of that time.

`sys_time` is a `time_point` based on `system_clock`.  This tracks UTC (Unix time).

The expression `local_days{ymd} + hms` converts `ymd` and `hms` to `local_time` with a precision of `seconds`.  `local_days` is just another `local_time` `time_point`, but with a precision of `days`.

The type of `ut` is `time_point<system_clock, seconds>`, which has a convenience type alias called `sys_seconds`, though `auto` makes that name unnecessary in this code.

To unpack the `sys_seconds` into an integral type, the `.time_since_epoch()` member function is called which results in the `duration` `seconds`, and then the `.count()` member function is called to extract the integral value from that `duration`.

When `int` is 32 bits, this function is susceptible to the [year 2038 overflow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).  To fix that, simply change the return type of `unixtime` to return a 64 bit integral type (or make the return `auto`).  Nothing else needs to change as `std::chrono::seconds` is already required to be greater than 32 bits and will not overflow at 68 years.  Indeed `std::chrono::seconds` is usually represented by a signed 64 bit integral type in practice, giving it a range greater than the age of the universe (even if the scientists are off by an order of magnitude).

Comment: Thank you Howard, you are too kind. TIL `std::chrono::locate_zone`, which is an extremely pleasant surprise for me, thank you. This will remove the need for me to maintain a library in my codebase that exports `tzfree`, `tzalloc`, `mktime_z`, `localtime_rz` for timezone conversions without messing with `TZ` environment variable. +1

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed response!  I'll definitely give ```<chrono>```  a shot as well.

Comment: Glad this was useful.  Fwiw, there exists a free, open-source preview of this part of C++20 here:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date  This works with C++11/14/17.  It exists only because it was the field experience for what became C++20 chrono.  That is, I'm not trying to sell it.  I already "sold" it to the C++ committee. :-)